# Answer a Loaded Question (with Lojban!)

Tags: code-golf

A loaded question is something like 'Have you stopped swearing?' in which both yes and no answers mean that I have swore, meaning it is impossible to answer the question if I haven't swore.

However, the constructed language Lojban has a word na'i, which means there is something wrong with what you just said.

Your input should be a list of newline-seperated strings containing the following tokens:

1. `start`  followed by any integer (e.g. `-1`, `0`, `1`)
2. `stop`  + integer
3. `haveYouStopped`  + integer

You can assume that each `stop`  *n* is followed by the corresponding `start`  *n*.

Then for each `haveYouStopped`   *n* in the code:

- Print `Yes, I have.` + a newline if the last `stop`  *n* occurs before the last `start`  *n*
- Print `No, I have not.` + a newline if the last `stop`  *n* occures after the last `start`  *n*, or at least one `start`  *n* but no `stop`  *n* is found in the previous line
- Print `.i na'i` + a newline if no `start`  *n* occurs in the previous lines.

The last newline is optional.

Examples:

```
start 1
stop 1
haveYouStopped 1
```

Output: Yes, I have.

```
start 1
haveYouStopped 1
```

Output: No, I haven't.

```
haveYouStopped 1
```

Output: .i na'i

All code is counted in UTF-8 bytes. Codepoints outside the UTF-8 range are not allowed. Use any language, shortest code wins. Also, no external sources are allowed.

Comment: What is a "list of newline-separated strings"? Do you mean one string with portions delimited by newlines?

Comment: Please add more testcases, for example, more than one queries, start after stop, multiple start without stop (is it allowed?), stop without start (is it allowed?), `n` other than 1, testcases with multiple different n...

Comment: In your rules you say the output is `No, I have not.`, but in your test case the output is `No, I haven't.`. So should it be `have not`, or `haven't`, or can we choose either?

Comment: This site has a special question called the Sandbox where you can post your challenges before you put them on the main site, so you can get feedback on how they can be improved. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>92</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
L$ms`d( \S+)$(?<=([pt])\1$.+?)?
$2.i na'i
p.+
YesI.
t.+
NoIn't.
I
, I have
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcmxCsIwEIDh/Z7ihkATogdxVjIHxKVTsYKBBsxgcjSnrx/t3uXng39Nkkt0vV/Vuz0XjfNojdL@fNF3loeZnSLrjQd1oowlDhmYLEypBQL561ZDGYQgwAEDvuI39b51qp9RKnNa8OigSVxlw96qvHt@) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
L$ms`d( \S+)$(?<=([pt])\1$.+?)?
$2.i na'i
```

For each `haveYouStopped` line, look for a previous `start` or `stop` line with that signed integer, and if so prefix the output with the final `t` or `p`, otherwise just output `.i na'i`.

```
p.*
YesI.
t.*
NoIn't.
I
, I have
```

If a start or stop was found then decode it to the desired output string.

Edit: Saved 17 bytes and corrected the Yes/No order thanks to @tsh.

Since this question counts in UTF-8, I didn't post a [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) answer, but had it been allowed it would have been 59 SBCS bytes:

```
≔⦃⦄θＷＳ¿№ιs§≔θΣι⪫⪪⎇№ιp¦Yes,.¦No,n't.¦,¦, I have⟦∨§θΣι.i na'i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bU8xTgMxEOzzipWbrCXnJDqkqwLVUQDS0URRCnNxcisZ27HXAYR4CU0KEDyGD-Q3OBxFJNLsrmZ2Znbfvrpex85ru9t9ZF5Nzvff05Ro7fDlVcFG1qPHnqwBbFzI3HIkt0YpgVaAlz47RlIgkijQoJty45bmCTcK2vyAJBVceXLYBkuMdyY6HZ-PpEGUDTEzSVWiDNdeuTFXv6AaKjTQ660pETUYmwzcliMY5zcR_4UdBBWB02MSciHr93Tfpb_PPudisrVisb842M18btmHYJZwNkqsI5d-gvDhFD44_gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
≔⦃⦄θ
```

Start with all questions being impossible.

```
ＷＳ
```

Loop through the input strings.

```
¿№ιs
```

Does this string resolve a question?

```
§≔θΣι⪫⪪⎇№ιp¦Yes,.¦No,n't.¦,¦, I have
```

If so then save the appropriate answer.

```
⟦∨§θΣι.i na'i
```

Otherwise, output the saved answer, or the impossible answer if one wasn't saved.

Comment: I have no idea how Retina works, but maybe this is correct: [tio](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30cltzghRUEjJkVbU0XD3sZWI7qgJFZTIcZQRU/bXtOeS8VIL1MhL1E9k6tAT4srMrXYU4@rBMjyy/fMUy/R4/Lk0lHwVMhILEv9/x9ERuaXBpfkFxSkpigYcmEIFJckFpVgk8CiMr@AKIVoAkZQO4wwJbDbQYRCAA)

Comment: [Seems to output the `Yes`/`No` in the incorrect order in this case](https://tio.run/##XYqxCsMgFEX39xUPIsSQImrWFmehdOkUaqGCQjNEJdr@vjXQKcs9l8PZfFmCFbVeyZpfDqlx40CoOl8eqTwpGkHYqIZB7SpRI9sF0knSTcA5sAWD7RcQHGafNQMh4BZ16AsDDSfU@LZfX@u@c/zcS0zJOxSQi90Kyj@nxpgaDp08iukH), and it also [doesn't work for negative `n`](https://tio.run/##ZYq9CsIwFEb3@xQXGmhCbcjPqnQOiItTsYKBBszQJLTR14/N4KLLdw6Hb3XZBytLOZNle8xIp7ljhA7H0y3lO8VJEt4NjA01JTqpXYE0ijQahADuMdjWgxQwus1wkBIu0YQ2czBwQINP@3al1B3j65pjSm7GXsKW7ZqxV1/Ru8RU@ftVf0V/AA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen @‌tsh's correction already fixed the accidental Yes/No swap; I'll fix negative `n` later because I don't want to merge it in.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), (68<sup>†</sup> [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)) 107 bytes<sup>UTF-8</sup>

<sup>† Since the challenge states the answers should be counted in UTF-8 bytes for some reason.. -_-</sup>

```
|ηʒθ'hÅ?}ε€#R.¡θ}н€н€θDgi".i na'i"ëJ…dptQi“Yes, I€¡.“ë“No, I€¡€–.“]»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5tz2U5PO7VDPONxqX3tu66OmNcpBeocWnttRe2EvkAMmzu1wSc9U0stUyEtUz1Q6vNrrUcOylIKSwMxHDXMiU4t1FDyBig4t1ANyD68GEn75MCEg8ahhMkgi9tDu//8zEstSI/NLg0vyCwpSUxQMuYpLEotKFIygtK4xkJFfAKLRVBqhC@gaAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
|                           # Get all inputs as a list of strings
 η                          # Pop and push its prefixes
  ʒ     }                   # Filter this list of prefixes, keeping those where:
   θ                        #  The last string of the prefix
      Å?                    #  ends with
    'h                     '#  an "h"
ε                           # Map over each prefix ending with "haveYouStopped"
 €#                         #  Split each inner string by spaces
   R                        #  Reverse this list of pairs
    .¡ }                    #  Then group it by:
      θ                     #   The last item of the pair (the numbers)
        н                   #  Keep the first group (of the reversed list)
 €н                         #  Keep the strings of each inner pair
   €θ                       #  Keep the last letter of each string
     Dg                     #  Duplicate, pop and push the amount of characters in this list
       i                    #  If this length is 1 (thus only "haveYouStopped"):
        ".i na'i"           #   Push string ".i na'i"
       ë                    #  Else:
        J                   #   Join the list of 2 or 3 characters to a string
         …dptQi             #   If it's equal to "dpt" (thus "haveYouStopped,stop,start"):
               “Yes, I€¡.“  #    Push dictionary string "Yes, I have."
              ë             #   Else:
               “No, I€¡€–.“ #    Push dictionary string "No, I have not."
]                           # Close both if-else statements and map
 »                          # Join the list of strings by newlines
                            # (after which it is output implicitly with additional trailing newline)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“Yes, I€¡.“` is `"Yes, I have."` and `“No, I€¡€–.“` is `"No, I have not."`.

Comment: It just says "Codepoints outside the UTF-8 range are not allowed", but these are all perfectly fine Unicode characters, so I think this should count.

Comment: @noodleman Ah wait. I mixed up UTF-8 with ASCII.. -_- My bad!

Comment: It still says "all code should be counted in UTF-8 bytes" however.

Comment: @noodleman reverted that part.. And added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 255 bytes

255 bytes. It can be golfed much more.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZHBTgIxEIbvPsWkF9oEmhgvZs2aeOCgCXggHggSUnYL1JS2aQeUII_hyQsXvfhEPI3OwqIJnmbmm87MP9P3z1Qoqy6-Bqzl_LOKjg13d378pAuEjjIO1mcAZh58RNg_lcbLnl_EQp8mCm8tlRnv5HyBamy1HH0scNK63H2XegKBY9bDaNy0WWYdFQZ1cDDD_D_iQmQPzmC-RpmCNcjZo2NCToxFHbse-Uia1J4HXBH0Uatitrb59VJZuIlRrXjRXIrcHouBiSsz4QVJdUjLJc4SE6Lk9OiEB-Ksr1MTbmGmlloybZNmXX8EroEHBoG0onW8lFON97FNjC-bTBpwqmGoz2ZTn-ENoDrEnEZwFacpO6istx6KDKptId8fHaBaA_ULgX0IwBirPYDXhIpOf_4HKlV9v-ihD0GXvxkqkokGhA6NNG5P6SuoryB_c1aL224P9gc)

```scala
def p(t:String,d:Map[String,String]=Map[String,String]()):Unit={t.split("\n").filterNot(_.isEmpty).foreach{l=>val Array(c,v)=l.split(" ");if(c.contains("s"))d(v)=if(c.contains("p"))"Yes, I have."else"No, I haven't."else println(d.getOrElse(v,".i na'i"))}}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVK9TiMxEJauzFOM3GBLiSVEg6KjoKCgCBThCgQRMhtvMPLalj3LgSBPQkMDDW_E0zDe9SYCIRpbnvl-Zsbz_JYqZdXe-wWbOP9fRccWL68t1pP9jz_v_vpWVwgzZRw8jgBME3xE6CjSeDn3baz090TlrSWa8U42Laprq0cEWeoaQvSVTulM3yNHOqYwx2jcagxLU9GrwOVMhYsh098LOPgty4WYwj9nkGC5UIA7ZcEapxNFspVMwRrk7NIxIWtjUccTj_xKmnTUBHwQHav2EXimwd9JTxdFr1c8jFE98Mo3jXLLcQ61WpBDhg4OwERhmBoGLA3FIY0xcZaY2IpC1znfCP1MCZnCznUawzHcqDstGWibNLATP4TcDkpWVNfl7jBbq0CzQut4tpQrjafxiAC9-RiYNODUjiGvLzL5XA8_2FBBXMVVmvazKB-x-Gn8eexwULQYY5s6nhIq2pbdbSA3cO7bOfoQ9HKTIZJMZBBmZGncqG_i6w6Jrrx1v7NldV_K_Qk)

```scala
object Main {
  import scala.io.Source
  import scala.collection.mutable

  def processText(text: String, dict: mutable.Map[String, String] = mutable.Map[String, String]()): Unit = {
    val lines = text.split("\n").filterNot(_.isEmpty)
    for (line <- lines) {
      val Array(command, value) = line.split(" ")
      if (command.contains("s")) {
        dict(value) = if (command.contains("p")) "Yes, I have." else "No, I haven't."
      }
      else {
        println(dict.getOrElse(value, ".i na'i"))
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val text =
      """
        |start 1
        |haveYouStopped 1
      """.stripMargin
    processText(text)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, <s>160</s> 158 bytes

```python
def d(t,i={}):
 for l in t.strip().split("\n"):
  c,v=l.split()
  if"s"in c:i[v]="Yes, I have."if"p"in c else"No, I haven't."
  else:print(i.get(v,".i na'i"))
```

-2 thanks to UndoneStudios

(Assumes that you are referring to taking input as a newline-delimited string)

#### Ungolfed version

```python
def decode(text):
    data = {}
    for line in text.strip().split("\n"):
        command, value = line.split()
        if "s" in command:
            data[value] = "Yes, I have." if "p" in command else "No, I haven't."
        else:
            print(data.get(v, ".i na'i"))
```

Comment: [-2 bytes?](https://tio.run/##NY5BC8IwDIXv@xUhF1sYBfE22A/w4sWTqIexdi4w29LEgYi/fWail4T3vrxH8lPGFHfL4sMA3khN7ettmwqGVGACiiCOpVA21nGeSAxeIq4H0NdzO/1Mq5oGZNRA39B5vrZ4ClzDHsZuDg4V5i@EMHHAQ/qjuBGHml7tJheKYsjdgpi5RkcQuw2htQvdcyoC/OTKG536lKfoSui8UczSKd1WLCnrWotP6XFUlYOH7Qc)